# FCC ID number through code

Tags: android

Is it possible to get the FCC ID number of a device through code? It can usually be found behind the battery. I know the serial number is possible to retrieve, but I cannot seem to get the FCC ID.

Comment: The FCC ID is presumably per *model*, not per *device* and it is not really apparent why there would be a means to obtain this at runtime.

Comment: So the only way is to get the model number and cross-reference it?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find the FCC ID of a device by searching the model and "site:fccid.io" (without quotes) or if you look up the company on https://fccid.io, you can see all the models of the device they product and the corresponding FCC ID.